# Superscript not working in a web browser

Tags: html

I'm doing some front end development and the craziest thing is happening. When I use the `<sup></sup>` tag, it is not functioning. No matter what I try to superscript it only displays correctly when viewed in a live setting in [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) but not in any browser. What am I missing? Is the tag deprecated?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Htk5G/ maybe you have a reset stylesheet that makes the tag look like everything else?

Comment: What browser are you trying to view it in? If IE have you set your page doctype?

Answer (score 40):

I had the same issue.  It was a CSS conflict.  Skylar was close but I'll do you one better.

```
sup {font-size:xx-small; vertical-align:super;}
```

;-) ahhhh, works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks...this works almost perfectly; except the font being too small `font-size: small` is preferrable

Answer (score 10):

When a widely supported html tag like sup or sub is not working, look for conflicting css.

A great place to start is by searching the Reset statement applied at the top of the css. Sub and Sup are usually part of this reset, which means they've been nutralized in your theme initially to protect you from browser specific defaults. That's a good thing, but...

The problem arises when the theme author fails to redefine specific tags. Here's some css to help define sup and sub so they work again:

```
sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

My guess is you might have reset the default styles on sup.

You can always reapply them:

```
sup {font-size:xx-small; vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 3):

### `sup` works in all browsers - check your CSS with Firebug

I suggest you use Firebug and check your CSS defined on the `<sup>` element. It will give you a much better understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The tag isn’t deprecated and normally works: <sup>This is superscript</sup>

It’s hard to give a better answer without more information from you.

Answer (score -1):

It must be in a conflict with a CSS rule, because I have tested it alone and it works.